# preg_match() not matching img src

Tags: php, regex

I have this string in a php variable.

```
$str = 'This is an iamge: <img src="images/Christmas.PNG" width=70%; height=40%">';
```

The pattern I am searching:

```
$pattern = '/<img src="(.*?)>/g';
```

I then have this `preg_match()`

```
preg_match($pattern, $str, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);
```

When i go to print `$matches` either directly by `echo $matches` or in a foreach loop, the variable is null.

Why is this happening? Thanks.

Comment: There is no `g` *global* flag in PHP. Use `preg_match_all` for getting all matches. Further your pattern would match `images/Christmas.PNG" width=70%; height=40%"` probably you wanted [`<img src="([^"]+)`](https://regex101.com/r/SKikJY/1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Don't use regexes for parsing HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454). There are tools designed for this very thing.

You can use [`DOMDocument`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) to parse the HTML and then easily get the value of the `src` attribute:

```
$previous_value = libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$string = 'This is an iamge: <img src="images/Christmas.PNG" width=70%; height=40%">';
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($string);
echo $dom->getElementsByTagName('img')->item(0)->getAttribute("src");
libxml_clear_errors();
libxml_use_internal_errors($previous_value);
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/LvN6g)

Comment: When I use this, it doesn't echo anything on my screen.

Comment: You should as this works for PHP versions all the way back to 5.1. Make sure you don't have a syntax error in your code.

Comment: thanks i had it before it was initialised. The reason i wanted strpos was i need the index of the substring (the first index). How can I do that?

Comment: I'm away from a computer right now but something like `$position = strpos($string, 'src');` should do the trick.